# Lambda Selectolax Import partially initialized module 'selectolax'

Tags: python, lambda, module, html-parsing

i tryed to fix this problem for hours now but i can't solve it. I did read through some similiar questions but they coudnt help me.

I want to use the Selectolax HTMLParser Module inside my AWS Lambda Function.
I Import the module like this from an Layer like this:

`from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser`

I always get the error:
"errorMessage": "cannot import name 'parser' from partially initialized module 'selectolax' (most likely due to a circular import)

The Problem lays not in the Name of My Function/File, i called it "Test123". As Selectolax is a public Module, i was afraid to change something after installing it with pip.
I reinstalled the package at least 3 times and uploaded it again as a layer.

Comment: What version of `selectolax` are you using? I see a new version (0.3.12) was just pushed to PyPI a few hours ago. Perhaps it has a bug in it. You can install an older version using `pip install "selectolax<0.3.12"`.

Comment: @MattDMo i reinstalled the package with an older version and uploaded it as my lambda layer. Then it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Package with an older version(0.3.11) did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the package with an older version did not work for me. The problem I had was that I am using the arm64 architecture of lambda. Since selectolax is written in C you need to ensure it builds for the correct architecture.

If you are using SAM cli you can build for the right architecture locally by doing `sam build --use-container`

To build it properly from an AWS Lambda Layer you have to specify both the compatible architecture and the BuildArchitecture:

```yaml
  LamdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: name-of-layer
      ContentUri: ./src/my-layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9
      CompatibleArchitectures:
        - arm64
      Metadata:
        BuildMethod: makefile
        BuildArchitecture: arm64
```

Check [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3747) on the aws-sam-cli github repository for details around the BuildArchitecture parameter.

You can check if the library is properly compiled by downloading the lambda layer and looking for the file `/python/selectolax/lexbor.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so` If it's either darwin (macbook) or x86 it's built for the wrong architecture.